# slow textarea in internet explorer after big table list

Tags: php, javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

I'm working on an ecommerce website for my work that gives me articles that can be ordered. Below my list of articles I have a textarea where you can give comments, when my list of articles is long the typing in this textarea is very slow.

When I have small lists everything goes fine, but with large lists ie hangs. No other webbrowser has this issue.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Upload your code, so that we can test it?

Comment: You are not in quirks mode are you? what version of IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be javascript code which listens events on textarea and do something with it (keydown, keyup, keypress). If it's so than this code related to each article and how many articles you have that much events are set up.

Comment: I have a keyup on my amount box but not on my comment box. So that can't be the problem. The problem also doesn't occure in other browsers.

Comment: 1. try to profile using firebug you will see what functions are eating cpu more.

Comment: 2. save page, remove some Javascripts and open it in browser

Comment: I've removed some javascript and indeed it seems that internet explorer falls over some of my javascript. How come that firefox doens't have this problem?

Comment: probably firefox do some checks and suspending code if it's eating too much system resources